# Why can Array.Length and Array.Count() not be assigned to const values?

Tags: c#, arrays, constants

I wanted to follow some excellent C++ advice of calculating the array length once and then using a value without having to call a function like so:

Instead of:

```
for( int i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i )
```

I write

```
const int size = arr.length; // or arr.Count()
for( int i = 0; i < size; ++i )
```

After reading a different thread ([Is it costly to do array.length or list.count in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262934/is-it-costly-to-do-array-length-or-list-count-in-a-loop)) I noticed that the performance gain is moot and that this is C# and not C++.

The second reason for this was to initialize my array with a value:

`const int size = arr.Length;`

`int[] primes_ = new int[size];`

So my question is this:

Why can't I declare this anyway? It spits me the error:

`Error  2   The expression being assigned to 'length' must be constant`

Which is very confusing because my value IS constant. However, when I remove the `const`, poof goes the message. ...What?

The initialization of Length reads:

`public int Length {get;}` from MSDN. Which is especially confusing because my last question [(Get-Set Accessor functionality differs on existence of get-set keyword)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451146/get-set-accessor-functionality-differs-on-existence-of-get-set-keyword) explicitly gave me the answer of "It's not possible to declare only get and leave set absent."

It's not clear to my why I can declare `int size = arr.Length`, but not `const int size = arr.Length`. Why is this so?

Comment: This is a dup of a bunch of questions. The simple answer is const in C# means compile time constant and not as in c++ where it means assign to once

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `const` keyword requires the value to be known at compile time - the .Net compiler cannot determine the value of `arr.length` when you compile the code, so you can't assign it to a `const`.

With regard to your last question about getters and setters - you must declare both *only* if you use the short cut syntax: i.e. `private long n { get; private set; }`.  If you use the full, verbose property declaration with a local field, you can declare just a get:

```
private long _n = 0;
private long N { get { return _n; } }
```

Answer (score 4):

Definition with `const` in C# requires an initializer that can be evaluated at compile time.

[Look here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6w8fe1b.aspx)

You can use `readonly`